# Django ORM IF statement

Tags: django, orm, aggregate

I have this table

[image]

With SQL query i can get aggregated information about total "amount" for avery car, and amount of "checked"|"uncheked" rows and sign of finished checking for all rows for one car:

```
SELECT 
car_id 
, SUM(amount) as total_amount
, Sum(IF(checked=1,1,0)) as already_checked
, Sum(IF(checked=0,1,0)) as not_cjecked
, IF(Sum(IF(checked=0,1,0))=0,1,0) as check_finished
FROM 
    refuels_flow
GROUP BY car_id
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
| car_id | total_amount | already_checked | not_cjecked | check_finished |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
|      1 | 1300         | 1               | 12          |              0 |
|      2 | 300          | 3               | 0           |              1 |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+
```

The question is - how i can do this with Django ORM (without use of raw query)?

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To obtains the same SQL output, you may use the following queryset:

```
already_checked = Sum(Func('checked', function='IF', template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s=0, 0, 1)'))
not_checked = Sum(Func('checked', function='IF', template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s=0, 1, 0)'))
check_finished = Func(
        not_checked,
        function='IF', template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s=0, 1, 0)'
)
Refuels.objects.values('car_id').annotate(
    total_amount=Sum('amount'),
    already_checked=already_checked,
    not_checked=not_checked,
    check_finished=check_finished
)
```

Check the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/ref/models/expressions/) on expressions for more informations.

Now, `already_checked` could be simplified with:

```
already_checked = Sum('checked')
```

And instead of having the `not_checked` and `check_finished` annotations, you could annotate the count and easily compute them in Python, for example:

```
qs = Refuels.objects.values('car_id').annotate(
    count_for_car=Count('car_id'),
    total_amount=Sum('amount'),
    already_checked=Sum('checked'),
)

for entry in qs:
    not_checked = entry['count_for_car'] - entry['already_checked']
    check_finished = not_checked == 0
```